# Center Manifolds

Tags: equation-solving

```
a[x_, y_] := -1
b[x_, y_] := x
c[x_, y_] := x
d[x_, y_] := -(1/2)

h[x_] = c1*x^2 + c2*x^3 + O[x]^4;

h[0] = 0;

D[h[x], x] = 0 /. {x -> 0};

cz3 = Solve[ h[a[x, y]*x + b[x, h[x]]] == c[x, h[x]]*h[x] + d[x, y], {c1, c2}]
```

I am using Implicit Function Theorem/center Manifold to determine stability of the fixed point give me P(x*)=1.
But for the above `h`, I need to determine `c1` and `c2` but my programme gives me nothing. I know I think simple but I have recently started to use *Mathematica*. Please help me! I don't know what to use in here.

Comment: If you wrap the first argument in `Solve` with `Normal` (i.e., `Solve[Normal[your equation]],...]`) you get some result; is it what you expect as the output?

Comment: No, it should give c2=0 and c1=2/3. But thank you now I know using Normal. It gives me something to think about. Thank you for your respond.

Comment: Polynomial equations supposed to be equal each other. That's why to do that we have definite c1 and c2.

Comment: Are the left- and right-hand sides of your equation evaluating to what you expect? Is `h[a[x, y]*x + b[x, h[x]]]` supposed to be 0?

Comment: When you use Big O for those values of c1 and c2 equation holds. For your last question no it is not supposed be 0 I guess.

Answer (score 2):

What does not allow the system to be solved is the term `O[x]^4` in the equation for `h[x]`. If you remove it, the system returns the solution:

```
    a[x_, y_] := -1
b[x_, y_] := x
c[x_, y_] := x
d[x_, y_] := -(1/2)
h[x_] = c1*x^2 + c2*x^3;
Solve[h[a[x, y]*x + b[x, h[x]]] == c[x, h[x]]*h[x] - d[x, y], {c1, 
  c2}]
```

yielding

```
(* {{c2 -> -(1/(2 x^4)) - c1/x}}  *)
```

To obtain the solution `c2=0 and c1=2/3` you mentioned in one of comments you seems to need one more equation.

Comment: But I don't have any other equation. When you put h[x] into the function in the Solve by hand ı find 'c2=0' and 'c1=2/3' when you compare the degree of the polynomials for both sides. In the program maybe I need something different from Solve.

Comment: @Anıl Uyar All that is up to you. You know the problem in question and its internal logic, I do not. My statement is only that if one needs to find two independent parameters, as a rule he needs to have two independent equations.